# JQPlot chart cannot be shown if I specify formatString for date

Tags: jqplot

Here is the data that I want to show in the chart:

```
var theStuff = [ [ [ "09-07-2016", 5.9 ] ], [ [ "09-07-2016", 2.0 ] ],
                [ [ "09-07-2016", 2.0 ] ], [ [ "09-07-2016", 2.0 ] ] ];
```

Here is the axes options that I want to display:

```
axes : {
                xaxis : {
                    label : 'Time',
                    renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions : {
                        formatString : ‘%Y-%m-%d’,
                        angle : -30
                    }
                },
                yaxis : {
                    label : 'CPU Usage (%)',
                    min : 0,
                    max : 100,
                    tickOptions : {
                        suffix : '%'
                    }
                }

            }
```

The chart cannot be showed if I have `formatString : ‘%Y-%m-%d’`, but the chart can be showed if I comment this line out. Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using this apostrophe (`‘`) instead of a string single quote (`'`) in the `formatString` expression.